# How to use Chrome WebDrive with Selenium through Wrappers?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

Working text cases in C# .NET with Selenium 3.4.0 using the Chrome WebDriver. I have a wrapper that handles which browser to run the test with and after doing this it will not initialize either browser.

Error: (from my browserfactory file meaning that driver = null but it's explicitly being set from logintext)

```
Message: System.NullReferenceException : The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser.
```

LoginTest.cs :

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using qa.PageObjects;
using qa.WrapperFactory;
using System.Configuration;

namespace qa.TestCases
{
    class LoginTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            // Sign in through google first, so we don't have to follow new tabs
            BrowserFactory.InitBrowser( "Chrome" );
            BrowserFactory.LoadApplication( ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"] );

            Page.Login.ClickOnMyAccount();
            Page.Login.LoginToGoogle();

            BrowserFactory.CloseAllDrivers();
        }
    }
}
```

BrowserFactory.cs :

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace qa.WrapperFactory
{
    class BrowserFactory
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, IWebDriver> Drivers = new Dictionary<string, IWebDriver>();
        private static IWebDriver driver;

        public static IWebDriver Driver
        {
            get
            {
                if ( driver == null )
                    throw new NullReferenceException( "The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser." );
                return driver;
            }
            private set
            {
                driver = value;
            }
        }

        public static void InitBrowser( string browserName )
        {
            switch ( browserName )
            {
                case "Firefox":
                    if ( Driver == null )
                    {
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                        Drivers.Add( "Firefox", Driver );
                    }
                    break;

                case "Chrome":
                    if ( Driver == null )
                    {
                        driver = new ChromeDriver();
                        Drivers.Add( "Chrome", Driver );
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void LoadApplication( string url )
        {
            Driver.Url = url;
        }

        public static void CloseAllDrivers()
        {
            foreach ( var key in Drivers.Keys )
            {
                Drivers[key].Close();
                Drivers[key].Quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is getting thrown before the driver is initialized.

When Driver gets called here in InitBrowser()...

```
case "Chrome":
          if ( Driver == null )
```

This get statement is executed and the private variable driver is null...

```
public static IWebDriver Driver
{
    get
    {
        if ( driver == null )
            throw new NullReferenceException( "The WebDriver browser instance was not initialized. You should first call the method InitBrowser." );
        return driver;
```

One way to fix this is to check if the private driver variable is null on initialization..

```
    public static void InitBrowser( string browserName )
    {
        switch ( browserName )
        {
            case "Firefox":
                if ( driver == null )
                {
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                    Drivers.Add( "Firefox", Driver );
                }
                break;

            case "Chrome":
                if ( driver == null )
                {
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    Drivers.Add( "Chrome", Driver );
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```